# When should use Datacontext and when use window.resources in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF - MVVM. I am confused about when I should use

```
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
```

and when use I should use

```
<Window.DataContext>
</Window.DataContext>
```

I am trying to understand WPF with MVVM recently. I have created the ViewModel

```
 public class MainWindowVeiwModel 
        { 
    
            private string myMessage = "Some text from MainWindowViewModel";
    
            public string MyMessage
            {
                get { return myMessage ; }
                set
                {
                    myMessage = value; 
                }
            } 
         }
```

I am trying to use MyMessage property in XAML view in TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyMessage }" />
```

So, which is the best approach, why use DataContext and not Window.Resources and ViceVersa...?

Comment: DataContext is the default source object for Bindings, i.e. those Bindings that do not explicitly specify a source, like your `{Binding MyMessage}`. So DataContext is what you want to set. You should have noticed that your Binding won't work when you declare the view model as resource. See also [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

`DataContext` determines where your Binding data comes from and goes to. Therefore, you will need to have a reference to your ViewModel either within the xaml of the View or within the code behind file associated with it.

`Resources` are definitions/links to items that aid your view execution. For example you may have a helper class that maps a boolean value provided by your `DataContext` (ViewModel) to a colour e.g. green for true, red for false.

This allows you to focus your ViewModel purely on handling data for the View to Bind to and not be involved within the presentation of that data.

Comment: "[Something] are definitions/links to items that aid your view execution. For example you may have a helper class that maps a boolean value provided by your DataContext (ViewModel) to a colour e.g. green for true, red for false". I would never guess that [Something] == Resources from you explanation

Comment: Odd. It shows as `Resources` (Resources flagged as code type) in my view